# Get Json/Xml out of larger text

Tags: java, json, xml, kotlin

I'm having a large text which looks like this

```
Some text blabla
<a><b attr="/>!" /></a>
Some other text ...
{ "field": "value", "inner": { "a":true, "b": false} }
Ans some more text
```

Within this text there are several valid xml and json parts. I would like to get the correct substring by passing the start index of the part I want. Like this:

```
String text = ..; // from above
String xml1 = util.getXml(text, 17); // 17 means to start search at "<a ..."
// expected xml1: <a><b attr="/>!" /></a>

String text = "..";
String xml2 = util.getXml(text, 20); // 20 means to start search at "<b at...."
// expected xml2: <b attr="/>!" />

String text = "..";
String json1 = util.getJson(text, 61); // 61 means to start search at "{ "fi..."
// expected json1: { "field": "value", "inner": { "a":true, "b": false} }
```

I guess it's a very special case because I didn't found *anything* related.

I'm thinking about regex and xml/json stream parsers to implement it on my own but I wanted to ask first if there is possibly any solution out there.

Comment: Is the large text well formatted/defined? or is it free formatted?

Comment: Completely free entered text